# Assign resources that each have a certain amount of work they can provide to tasks that require a certain amount of work

Tags: algorithms

I'm attempting to do a hobby automation project and have come to a roadblock. I have a certain problem I need to solve, but can't think of the solution nor what the name for the problem would be.

Say we have n tasks where each task requires $x_i$ amount of work to be done and m resources where each resource can provide $y_j$ work. The total amount of work required will equal the the total amount of work the resources can provide, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{m}x_j$. For all j from 1 to m, $y_j \in \left \{1, 2, 6, 12, 24\right \}$ and each $x_i = a*1 +b *2 + c*6+d*12+e*24$. I was looking at task assignment problems, but those seemed to be a bit overkill since they were concerned with optimization where I'm just simply trying to slot the correct blocks in the right place so that I don't have tasks that are given too few or too many resources.

My current guess is that you can iterate over each task, and give it the largest resource available that doesn't go over the amount of work that is left for the task to be completed. It's almost analagous to filling a jar with different sized rocks; the best way is to start with the largest rocks and then go down in size from there, so that the smaller rocks fill in the space between the larger ones. Am I not taking something into consideration that complicates this problem further? I'm sorry if this is an obvious one, but I'm a hobbyist programmer and couldn't think of the name of the problem or of a good set of keywords to google. The closest I could find is task assignment so far.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is the input, and what is the required output?

Comment: You seem to be aware that you can use any algorithm for [the assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  If your problem is the same problem, I don't understand why you are rejecting that solution and it doesn't seem reasonable to expect solutions that are much simpler.  If it's the same problem, then no, a greedy algorithm like you list is not optimal in the general case.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for the input. I'll try to find which assignment algorithm fits best for my needs. I was simply hoping to see if there was a simpler solution given the constraints that each resource can provide one of 5 different amounts of work, each task requires an amount of work that is some combination of those 5 amounts, and the amount of work required by all the tasks combined is the same that all of the resources combined can provide. Since I'm a hobbyist and not a learned professional, I don't know if there is some other name or keyword I was missing to find exactly what I needed.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The input would be our list of n tasks and m resources and an output would be an assignment of those resources to the tasks such that there every resource is used and every task has exactly the right amount of work being applied to it.

Comment: Instead of responding in the comments, please update your question with these details. Don't add an "EDIT:" paragraph, just modify your question so that it includes all necessary details.